# Parsing bad dates automatically with feeds and date api?

Tags: 7, entities, feeds, datetime, services

My company is trying to load an event calendar with events from another company's online calendar's web service. I'm using the Feeds Module and everything's working, except the dates because their service returns dates in a text format like so: 'MM/DD/YY[ - Ongoing]'. The Dates API doesn't seem to know how to handle this, so it just defaults to today's date.

I've tried using the Partial Date module, but there doesn't seem to be a way of feeding Feeds results into a partial date field. I've also tried talking the other company into fixing their service and returning proper dates, but they have no idea what they're doing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain if Feeds can handle this, but if you are importing CSV files, maybe [OpenRefine](http://openrefine.org/) is the quickest fix.